# Unable to access scope properties of parent directive in the child directive when parent scope is either true or isolated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-module

I'm building a custom login module directive with **parent** tag housing **child** tags like *username & password*. I've defined *username and password* in the parent scope and communicating it using controller function.

```
    angular.module('sampleModule', [])
        .directive("parent",function(){return {
            restrict : 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: false,
            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                $scope.username = 'Init value';
                $scope.setUsername = function(name){
                    $scope.username = name;
                };
                $scope.getUsername = function(){
                    return $scope.username;
                }
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                element.find('button').on('click', function(event){
                   alert('In Parent: '+ scope.username);
                });
            },
            template: '<div id="loginForm"><label>Parent: {{username}}</label><button>Check</button><br><br><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>'
        }})
        .directive("child",function(){return {
            restrict : 'E',
            require: '^parent',
            scope: true, //parent scope is available only when its true or false
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl){
                scope.$watch('username', function(newVal, oldVal){
                    if(newVal!=oldVal){
                        scope.setUsername(scope.username);
                    }
                });
            },
            template: '<input id="username" type="text" ng-model="username"><label>In Child: {{username}}</label>'
        }});
```

Its my first time working with directives and I've following doubts:

1. Can child directives inherit from the isolated scope of the parent directive?
2. I want the module data to be encapsulated(i.e. username & password information not available elsewhere in the app). So I'm thinking on making the parent directive scope containing username fields to be isolated. However when I make this parent scope properties are not accessible in the child scope. How do I fix this?
3. If in case I make the parent directive scope as *false* will its properties be accessible by the controller function housing it?
   For example: will the ***username*** available in **SomeController**?

   ```
   <div ng-controller="SomeController">
       <parent>
           <child></child>
       </parent>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Attach your getUsername function to `this` instead of scope:

```
this.getUsername = functon(){....
```

Then in your child directive you can access it with:

```
parentCtrl.getUsername();
```

To access the child scope from the parent you can do this:

```
var child = element.find('child');
var childScope = childElem.isolateScope();
console.log(childScope.username);
```

Comment: Like you mentioned I assigned properties to the _this_ rather than to scope in the parent directive. And I had to use **controllerAs** property in the parent directive to use the controller properties in the parent template. `controllerAs: ctrl` and in parent `template: '{{ctrl.username}}'`. **But how to do I access controller properties in the child template?!** controller properties are only available in the child's link function and not in template

Comment: just attach it to the scope, so in the link function set `scope.username = parentCtrl.getUsername();` now the username is available in the child template as a scope variable